# Error in Visual Studios C++ code. Lab4.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that counts up all the integers in a file and checks to see if they are even. And i keep getting this error associated with the "Check if they're even" part. Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isNotEven(int&);

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    int numberTot = 0;
    int numberOdd = 0;
    int check = 1;
    string line;

    while(check != -1)
    {
        getline(myfile,line);
        check = stoi(line);

        if (check != -1)
            numberTot++;

        if (isNotEven(check) == true)
            numberOdd++;
    }

    cout << "There are " << numberTot << " numbers in this file." << endl;
    cout << "There are " << numberOdd << " odd numbers in this file." << endl;
    char x;
    cin >> x;
}

bool isNoteEven(int& x)
{
    if (x%2 == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

I keep getting this error and am so confused as to why it is appearing

```
1>  Lab4.cpp
1>Lab4.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl isNotEven(int &)" (?isNotEven@@YA_NAAH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\CS1\Lab4\Debug\Lab4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: You have to fix the name of the function in the definition to `isNotEven` to match the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly spelt the function name, isNoteEven instead of isNotEven.

Comment: Man i never catch the little things ):